# Access parent and child variables in method defined in parent - PHP

Tags: php, oop, methods

I have a child object that inherits from a parent. Both have a static variable which has a different value in each object; I want to add that variable from both parent and child to an array when I instantiate the child. To save duplicating code, I've written a method (`addFoo`) in the parent which is called from both the parent and the child constructors. However, I can't seem to find a way to distinguish between the calls when the parent constructor is called from the child constructor (as you can see below, the output from the method is the same in both cases whether using `$this`, `self` or `static`).

```
class A {
    public static $foo = 'foo';
    
    public $thisvars = array();
    public $selfvars = array();
    public $staticvars = array();
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->addFoo();
    }
    
    public function addFoo() {
        $this->selfvars[] = self::$foo;
        $this->staticvars[] = static::$foo;
        $this->thisvars[] = $this::$foo;
    }
    
}

class B extends A {
    public static $foo = 'bar';
    
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->addFoo();
    }
}

$b = new B;
print_r($b->selfvars);
print_r($b->staticvars);
print_r($b->thisvars);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => foo
)
Array
(
    [0] => bar
    [1] => bar
)
Array
(
    [0] => bar
    [1] => bar
)
```

I can workaround this by passing the calling class through to the `addFoo` function (see below), but is there a better (correct?) way?

```
class C {
    public static $foo = 'foo';
    
    public $vars = array();
    
    public function __construct() {
        $this->addFoo(__CLASS__);
    }
    
    public function addFoo($class) {
        $this->vars[] = $class::$foo;
    }
    
}

class D extends C {
    public static $foo = 'bar';
    
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->addFoo(__CLASS__);
    }
}

$d = new D;
print_r($d->vars);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TqUUf)

Comment: From the perspective of `say`, the current object is an instance of class `B` (because that's what you're instancing), so it doesn't matter where you're calling it from: it will always give results relative to `B` (except for `__CLASS__` and `self` since they refer to the current class per se, but that doesn't help). I'm afraid anything else that would attempt figure it out would have to be a dirty trick such as parsing the stack trace. It would be interesting to know which problem(s) you're attempting to solve with that code, because there might be other ways to tackle them.

Comment: @Jeto thanks; that's the understanding I've been coming to. The problem I'm trying to solve is that I have a parent object that has a set of required attributes that need to be passed to the constructor; these need to be present for all instances of the parent and its children. The child may have additional required attributes, and I want to use the same function to process the required attributes for the parent (from the parent constructor) and the child (from the child constructor).

Comment: @Jeto I've rewritten the question to make it closer to my actual scenario and hopefully more self-explanatory.

Comment: if you want specific parent function can be call by child, you can set ```protected```, e.g ```protected function addFoo()```

Comment: @DonnyAkhmadSeptaUtama the functions are public so they can already be called by the child.

Comment: @Nick if your question is how to write with better way, that's my answer. for reference you can read this [refer](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_access_modifiers.asp) to more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having `addFoo` be called by every sub-constructor, one way would be to have a single `addFoos` method in the base class that is called by the base constructor, that would append all the `$foo` values starting from the late static binding class:

```
class A
{
    public static $foo = 'foo';

    public $vars = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addFoos();
    }

    private function addFoos()
    {
        $class = static::class;
        do {
            $this->vars[] = $class::$foo;
        } while ($class = get_parent_class($class));
    }

}

class B extends A
{
    public static $foo = 'bar';
}

class C extends B
{
    public static $foo = 'baz';
}

$a = new A;
print_r($a->vars);  // ['foo']

$b = new B;
print_r($b->vars);  // ['bar', 'foo']

$c = new C;
print_r($c->vars);  // ['baz', 'bar', 'foo']
```

That method is marked `private` as it's not supposed to be extended in this scenario (nor called from the outside).

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/YNWar)**

Comment: This looks pretty good. I especially like the fact that `addFoos` can be made private. I'm not sure if the ordering of execution child->parent as compared to parent->child in my code will make a difference to me, I'll need to play with it a bit.

Comment: The one issue with this is that if in class B there is no value for `$foo`, it will add in the inherited value from class A again.

Comment: Well, technically, if `B::$foo` isn't defined, then it's exactly the same as if it was defined with the same value as `A::$foo`. So it kinda makes sense.

Comment: Not sure if  `print_r($c->vars);  // ['baz', 'foo', 'foo']` would be what the user intended though.  Not defining the value in B, I would expect there not to be anything added.

Comment: Feels like that'd be twisting the inheritance principle a bit too much ;). I mean calling `B::$foo` from the outside would still yield `'foo'` so it'd only be empty from the perspective of `addFoos`. If that's really needed, you'd have to [make use of a bit of Reflection](https://3v4l.org/MH8cV). I don't see another way, though that's obviously far from clean/ideal--I'd consider changing the overall logic of the whole thing if it comes to that.

Comment: It may not be a problem (not that I like to poke holes in ideas >;), just that it's something to be aware of.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for pointing out that potential issue; in my code it's not a problem as `$foo` is defined at each level, being null/empty string as appropriate.

Comment: Having tested both answers, this one works better for my particular problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would alternatively consider another, more straightforward approach:

```
class A
{
    public static $foo = 'foo';

    public function getVars()
    {
        return [self::$foo];
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static $foo = 'bar';

    public function getVars()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getVars(), [self::$foo]);
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    public static $foo = 'baz';

    public function getVars()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getVars(), [self::$foo]);
    }
}

$a = new A;
print_r($a->getVars());  // ['foo']

$b = new B;
print_r($b->getVars());  // ['foo', 'bar']

$c = new C;
print_r($c->getVars());  // ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

You do have to redefine `getVars` on each subclass in this case, but after all, it makes sense for each class to decide which variables should be exposed. Your code becomes a bit less obscure / easier to maintain in the process.

And if a class doesn't need/want to "contribute", you can simply omit both the static property and the `getVars` extension for that class.

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/fmdqP)**

Notes:

- you can easily cache the variables into a `$vars` property inside `A` if needed,
- order is swapped from the other answer but you can obviously swap the `array_merge` if needed,
- in both this sample and the one from the other answer, I'm not sure if the `$foo` static properties need to be `public`, but I've left them like they were in your question.

Comment: Thanks for this - I really appreciate the time you are spending on the problem.

Comment: This is also a good solution, although it does require redeclaring `getVars` at each level of inheritance. I like that you can just have `$this->vars = $this->getVars();` in a constructor in `A` to cache all the results.